# Galleria - Load each image dynamically

Tags: jquery, dynamic, galleria

I'm looking for a way to load each image within Galleria (http://galleria.io/) dynamically.

At the moment every image loads when the page is loaded, and since there is 178 of them, it can get a bit sluggish. Is it possible to load them as they are viewed?

Let me know if you need any code that I'm using.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting thumbnails to false and then preload to 0. This will cause galleria to not create thumbnails which is what you need if you want to set the preload option to 0.

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    thumbnails: false,
    preload: 0
});
```

This is untested but is documented in the documentation http://galleria.io/docs/1.2/options/preload/

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Problem is I really need the auto generated thumbnails and really do not want to make 178 of my own. Guess I'll have to!

Comment: The best solution performance wise is to provide separate thumbnail images, especially if you have a lot of them. There are many server-side solutions that can automate this for you.

Answer (score 0):

you must create page control for first, after this one of the solutions is that save image names into hidden input boxes and get them unique ID and call them after clicking next or prev buttons. other solution is that, you can create php or other server side language code and call them individual...